# How do I set up wine to play steam games?

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux

Shoot, I know this question has been asked probably like 8000 times before, and I've tried probably about 8000 different ways to do this thing, and only one has worked.

I recently had to do a fresh install of my system (and like the numbskull that I am, I didn't think to save the one way to get the game to work). I've been looking for that tutorial for a while now and can't seem to find it, so if someone here could help me out (not necessarily with finding it, moreso with how I can get this working).

I want to play Osiris: New Dawn (and it works fabulously, trust me, I've done it before!). It's a 64bit game so a lot of the tutorials don't let me either install it, or run it (it runs into the missing .exe error). I've tried the PlayOnLinux deal, and it doesn't work. I've tried doing the wine tutorial to download steam in a 64bit installation deal, and that didn't work either (it wouldn't make the desktop file at first, then it either gave me the missing .exe error or it wouldn't let me install the game).

The tutorial I used before from what I can remember used wine to make a virtual desktop where steam ran inside and created an Osiris icon on my desktop. So I was wondering if any of ya'll could help me out with how to work wine into working with steam and 64bit games?

Answer (score 0):

When using winecfg you can create a virtual desktop and simply let steam create the shortcut for you, if that's the desired behavior.

For specific information about your game and wine setup please refer to the [wine appdb entry for steam](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444).
Bugs and issues are maintained by the community so you can check often to see if there's anything fixed in new wine versions or more known bugs and workarounds for the latest steam.